# Getting a ScriptReference from a ScriptResourceMapping definition in a custom control

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, custom-controls

I am building a custom control with client side scripts that I would like to reference using `ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping` (to make use of the `Path` and `DebugPath` attributes).

I would like the custom control to be easily ported to other projects - i.e. I would like to drag and drop the codebehind files (and eventually make the control a separate DLL, but for now the drag and drop will suffice).  I would therefore like to avoid (1) having the client script as an embedded resource, (2) referenced as a `WebResource` in the `AssemblyInfo`, or (3) have the `ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition` in `global.asax`.

In simple terms can I get the script management code to be in just the custom control's code?

At the moment I am getting an error stating that the script reference cannot be found in the assembly, and I guess I am setting the wrong assembly.

My custom control code is as follows:

```
Public Class MyControl
    Inherits System.Web.UI.LiteralControl 
    Implements ISectionControl, IScriptControl

    Private _scriptReference As ScriptReference

    Public Sub New()

        ' Add the resource mapping
        ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("MyControlScript", New ScriptResourceDefinition With {
            .ResourceAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly,
            .ResourceName = "MyControlScript.js",
            .Path = "Path.To.MyControlScript.minimised.js",
            .DebugPath = "Path.To.MyControlScript.original.js"
        })

        ' Set the script reference
        _scriptReference = New ScriptReference("MyControlScript.js", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.FullName)

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPreRender(e As System.EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnPreRender(e)

        ' Register the script
        ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterScriptControl(Of MyControl)(Me)

        ' Some code to set the Text of the literal control
        ' ...
    End Sub

    Public Function GetScriptDescriptors() As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of System.Web.UI.ScriptDescriptor) Implements System.Web.UI.IScriptControl.GetScriptDescriptors
        Return New ScriptDescriptor() {}
    End Function

    Public Function GetScriptReferences() As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of System.Web.UI.ScriptReference) Implements System.Web.UI.IScriptControl.GetScriptReferences
        Return New ScriptReference() {_scriptReference}
    End Function
End Class
```

I hope the question makes sense.  Thanks for taking the time to read through.

Ali

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered this myself, I was getting confused with the assemblies and the constructors for `ScriptReference`.  I just wanted a `ScriptReference` with the (mapped) name so I used the blank constructor and then set `Name`.  I could then remove the assembly information.

Adjusting the following sorted the problem out:

```
Public Sub New()

    ' Add the resource mapping
    ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("MyControlScript", New ScriptResourceDefinition With {
        .Path = "Path.To.MyControlScript.minimised.js",
        .DebugPath = "Path.To.MyControlScript.original.js"
    })

    ' Set the script reference
    _scriptReference = New ScriptReference() With {.Name="MyControlScript"}

End Sub
```